# MySQL options for specifying ON UPDATE on non-reference columns

Tags: mysql

We all know `ADD COLUMN updated_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for the updated_at column.

That got me thinking about what is permitted to specify in the "ON UPDATE" clause. I couldn't find anything in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html). Note that I am not talking about reference columns but about non-reference columns only.

I tried `ALTER TABLE on_update_test ADD COLUMN test_const INT ON UPDATE 123` but that results in an error.

So is `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` the only valid usage for ON UPDATE on non-reference columns? Or are there more options?

Comment: Read all RM, not a small part of it. [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Comment: BEFORE INSERT trigger allows to realize close to any needed logic, even complex one.